# Lambda expression null

Tags: c#, lambda, automapper

This is what I have

`Mapper.CreateMap<Domain.Code.CodeSection, EF.Code.CodeSection>().ForMember(dest => dest.Parent, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Parent.Id));`

This doesn't compile because `src.Parent.Id` is an `Int` and `dest.Parent` is an object.

All I want is to set `dest.Parent` to `null`.

Something like `Mapper.CreateMap<Domain.Code.CodeSection, EF.Code.CodeSection>().ForMember(dest => dest.Parent, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => null));`

Comment: Can't you just use the ForEach extension method and do something like:  .ForEach(x => x.Parent = null)? According to "All I want is to set dest.Parent to null", that should be enough.

Comment: Looks like you're using AutoMapper. I've updated your question's tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MapFrom` is used to connect properties - you want `ResolveUsing`:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Domain.Code.CodeSection, EF.Code.CodeSection>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Parent, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => null));
```

Comment: This is why this site is great. I can see that I didn't even really ask the question correctly - I can see it has to do more with automapper than lambda - and yet i still got an answer in 20 minutes. Thank you

Comment: Remember that if the answer was useful, consider upvoting it.